# COPY in TSV data enclosed by quotes; treat empty strings as NULLs

Tags: copy, vertica

I have a TSV file like this, except with many more columns:

```
"name"\t"color"\t"lucky_number"
"Nick"\t"Red"\t""
""\t"Blue"\t"8"
```

I'm trying to `COPY` this file into a table and have empty cells (i.e. `""`) be interpreted as NULLs, which fits the semantics I'm looking for.

I can't seem to get Vertica (7.2) to do this simple thing without having to repeat a lot of code for each column I'm loading.

For example:

```
COPY some_table (
    name,
    color,
    lucky_number
)
FROM LOCAL file
DELIMITER AS E'\t'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
SKIP 1;
```

This loads empty strings, which isn't what I want, and which breaks for non-string columns like `lucky_number`.

So I look through [the options mentioned in the docs](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPY/Parameters.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%2520Reference%2520Manual%7CSQL%2520Statements%7CCOPY%7C_____1) and try out `NULL AS '""'`, but this yields the following error message:

> ERROR 2735:  COPY ENCLOSING CHARACTER must not appear in the NULL specification

Searching around a bit more, it seems [the suggested way to handle this](https://community.dev.hpe.com/t5/Vertica-Forum/COPY-issue-loading-enclosed-data-with-NULLs/m-p/205817/highlight/true#M699) is to special case the empty string for every column you are loading. (!)

```
COPY some_table (
    name AS CASE WHEN name_raw = '' THEN NULL ELSE name_raw,
    name_raw FILLER VARCHAR,
    color AS CASE WHEN color_raw = '' THEN NULL ELSE color_raw,
    color_raw FILLER VARCHAR,
    lucky_number AS CASE WHEN lucky_number_raw = '' THEN NULL ELSE TO_NUMBER(lucky_number_raw),
    lucky_number_raw FILLER VARCHAR
)
FROM LOCAL file
DELIMITER AS E'\t'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
SKIP 1;
```

Is there no better way to do this?

Comment: @kermit to the rescue?

Comment: Gosh I could be completely off base here but I recall having a similar issue 5 years ago.  Do you think it has anything to do with ANSI/UTF types?  I'm not able to look up the control character difference and only remember the new line ones.  I recall having something similar with ANSI NULL setting in SQL Server  Sorry I couldn't be more help, I'm mobile at the moment.

Comment: @AliRazeghi - Could you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted. Am happy to clarify anything that's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe is the delimiter E'\t' , try to replace it.

It worked for me. i made the file a csv by using the command bellow.

```
sed -i 's/\\t/|/g' file
```

**Here is an example:**

- **Copy the initial you did it**

copy public.bla FROM LOCAL '/tmp/bla'  DELIMITER '|' ENCLOSED BY '"' SKIP 1 ;
Rows Loaded
0

(1 row)

**- Load using the | instead of \t :**

```
-- replace the delimiter
    sed -i 's/\\t/|/g' /tmp/bla 

-- see content
    cat /tmp/bla
    "name"|"color"|"lucky_number"
    "Nick"|"Red"|""
    ""|"Blue"|"8"

-- run copy with new delimiter   
    copy public.bla FROM LOCAL '/tmp/bla' DELIMITER '|' ENCLOSED BY '"' SKIP 1 ;";

-- see if data was inserted
            dbadmin=> select * from bla;
             name | color | lucky_number
            ------+-------+--------------
                  | Blue  | 8
             Nick | Red   |
```

If any can format this post , please do so !!!!!! why does it have to be so hard this code formatting :( !!!!

```
dbadmin=> SELECT ISNULL(name, 'NULL') FROM bla;
 ISNULL
--------

 Nick
```

Hi, so if you wanna put in null values where you got empty strings use the bellow copy command to load your data:

```
copy some_table(
v1 filler varchar(20) ,
v2 filler varchar(20) ,
v3 filler varchar(20) ,
name as  case when v1='' THEN 'NUUL' ELSE v1 END,
color as  case when v2='' THEN 'NULL' ELSE v2 END,
lucky_number as  case when v3='' THEN 'NULL' ELSE v3 END

)FROM '/tmp/some_table.csv' DELIMITER '|' ENCLOSED BY '"' SKIP 1 ;
```

- i hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Are you saying if I replace the tabs with pipes, then Vertica will automatically interpret the empty strings (i.e. `""`) as NULLs? Because that's not what I'm seeing.

Comment: See my edited post !

Comment: Are those blank values in the table NULLs or empty strings? What do you get for `SELECT ISNULL(name, 'NULL') FROM bla;`?

Comment: Right, what your latest edit shows is that Vertica has loaded empty strings, which isn't what I'm looking for. I want Vertica to load them as NULL values. From my question: "I'm trying to `COPY` this file into a table and have empty cells (i.e. `""`) be interpreted as NULLs, which fits the semantics I'm looking for."

Comment: Regarding your latest edit, I specifically called out this approach (special casing the empty string for each column) at the end of my question. I'm looking for a better way. :)